# Foreground Render washes out background Photo

Tags: light, image, masking

I have a Photo of some work colleagues with a small table in the foreground.
I have made (in blender) a bright shinny trophy to go on the Table. 
The trophy renders up really nicely when just done as a render scene. When I try to place it on the table in the foreground with all the lighting etc it washes out the photo.
I suspect there is a simple answer I'm just not too sure what to search for.
Any help appreciated.

Cheers Willy

I have changed the picture as I can't use the original but you should get the idea.  Im using Cycles, v2.73a
I have played with some settings on the background image, its just a mesh plane with an image texture.  I really don't know how to achieve what I'm after.  To light up the rendered cup appropriately the image gets overexposed.  I presume there is some way to create a mask or filter but I haven't been able to find anything that seems to explain how this might be done.

Image with cup in Material view
[image: Original jpg]

Render View
[image: Rendered view]

needs some work but looking good, I'll play with FoV and some more/less lighting Many Thanks :-)
[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload some screenshots showing the issue and what you tried?

Comment: Try putting the image texture through an emission shader

Comment: Hi, it seems to still do the same thing or the colours just go weird.  I tried mix shader with image texture and an emission shader. I've played with the mix shader percentage and also positive and negative values for the emission shader no luck. In the node editor I also put the Emission shader between the texture and the Defuse but that just made the image grey.

Comment: Oh, I meant plugging the image texture straight into an emission shader. I.e. `image` -> `emission` -> `surface output`.

Comment: sorry I over complicated it... this works well thanks 2 thumbs up :-).  Is there a way to stop the shadow on the image, I'll play with the depth of field I get how all that works and I'll move the image back a bit that might help but it would be simpler to have the image not accept shadows.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I used the Node Editor and added the Emission shader between the Image Texture and the Material Output.  in my case I set the Emission shader to 0.85 this seemed to give the right balance of light to offset the lighting that I was using and returned the image back to a more realistic looking image.

Answer (score 2):

I used the Node Editor and added the Emission shader between the Image Texture and the Material Output. I set the Emission shader to 0.85 this seemed to give the right balance of light to offset the lighting that I was using and mostly restored the colours in the background image.

I'll add some more lighting to match the image lighting better, adjust the Field of view, camera distance etc to get the focus looking right and match the image blur.

Many thanks for the advice.

[image]